# Why won't my event listeners work in a function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm having issues when trying to add an event listener to a div in a function.

```js
function cancelMove()
{
  alert("cancelMove called");
}

function createTile ( posX, posY, tileColor, id )
{
    var tile = document.createElement ( "tile" )
    tile.style.left = posX + "px"
    tile.style.position = "absolute"
    tile.style.top = posY + "px"
    tile.style.width = "75px"
    tile.style.height = "75px"
    tile.id = "tile" + id.toString()
    tile.addEventListener("click", () => cancelMove() );
    if ( tileColor%2 == 0 )
    {
        tile.style.backgroundColor = "#ebc5c5"
    }
    else
    {
        tile.style.backgroundColor = "#1a4018"
    }
    document.body.append(tile)
}

createTile(50, 60, 1, "id");
```

I'm trying to add an event listener that runs when any of the tiles are clicked. When I take the code out of the function, it works fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A live demo of a function that you never call which operates on HTML you didn't include isn't very useful. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Once the function is called and `cancelMove` is implemented it seems to run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. Try this snippet.

```html
<body></body>

<script>
    function cancelMove() {
        alert('cancelMove called');
    }

    function createTile(posX, posY, tileColor, id) {
        var tile = document.createElement('tile');
        tile.style.left = posX + 'px';
        tile.style.position = 'absolute';
        tile.style.top = posY + 'px';
        tile.style.width = '75px';
        tile.style.height = '75px';
        tile.id = 'tile' + id.toString();
        tile.addEventListener('click', () => cancelMove());
        if (tileColor % 2 == 0) {
            tile.style.backgroundColor = '#ebc5c5';
        } else {
            tile.style.backgroundColor = '#1a4018';
        }
        document.body.append(tile);
    }

    createTile(50, 60, 1, 'id');
</script>
```

Comment: This works, Thank you!